# Phonegap 3 doesn't copy plugins to platforms folder

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using Phonegap3 http://phonegap.com/install/ but I'm facing an issue with plugins:

After creating project using

`phonegap create my-app`

```
phonegap local build android
```

then I added a camera plugin using

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

then build project using 
`phonegap local build android`

it was working fine  but suddenly it stopped working, after investgating the issue I found that plugins are not copied to the android project although I can list all plugins using

```
phonegap local plugin list
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is fixed now, the issue was that **add plugin** command adds to plugin files to platforms project too, so the **build command** not copying these files during the build phase,
so all I had to do is to remove **plugins/** folder content and **platforms/** content then I did those steps:

- `phonegap local build android`
- `phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git`

After all the **add plugins commands should run only after all your platforms are added**.

For more information kindly check [this](http://www.badrit.com/blog/2014/7/28/phonegap-3-doesn-t-copy-plugins-to-platforms-folder)

Comment: does anyone know if phonegap team will fix this bug?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue building an iOS app. I've discovered that you won't have this issue if your project name starts with an uppercase letter. As long as the project name starts with an uppercase letter when you create it, you will be able to add plugins later.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, I found I had to add all the plugins before I created a build.

Comment: You mean if I've to use the Notification plugin only, I must add all of the plugins???

Comment: No, I mean If a created a project. Then build a platform, then added a plugin the plugin did not install correctly. However if I created a project then added the plugins then built the platform they would install correctly. I am not sure if this is the case across all version, but it was an issue I ran into on phonegap 3.0

Comment: i had the same problems

Comment: and they call it their super awesome 'plugin based architecture' for phonegap > 3

Answer (score 1):

I have to add a third party plugin(barcode) for a project, so i dupliqued other project and removed the folder Android, and then execute "cordova add platform android", but fails with cordova class not found, or another error for the plugin... so i list the plugins with cordova command, and saw all the plugins ok... so? why?.

The error is remove from explorer or manually... you have to delete from command line..

This was my solution.. and don´t have to re-add all the plugins... just

```
"cordova platform remove android"
"cordova platform add android"
```

and the "android/src/" folder gets populated as "android/bin/classes".. sound strange but works...

you will note that the results for command lines change for a plugin... example..

```
cordova platform add android
Creating android project...
Preparing android project
Starting installation of "cordova-plugin-barcodescanner" for android
Preparing android project
cordova-plugin-barcodescanner installed on android.
```

Cordova Versión 3.3

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to update Node.js (download latest from node.js website) then update Phonegap

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

Then reinstall the plugins.