# Phonegap 3.0 IOS plugins not found

Tags: ios, cordova

I´m getting this error in XCode:

```
2013-08-23 14:36:18.284 Tell The DJ[14955:c07] ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-08-23 14:36:18.284 Tell The DJ[14955:c07] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "Device1096677259",
  "Device",
  "getDeviceInfo",
  [

  ]
]
2013-08-23 14:36:18.285 Tell The DJ[14955:c07] CDVPlugin class CDVConnection (pluginName: NetworkStatus) does not exist.
2013-08-23 14:36:18.285 Tell The DJ[14955:c07] ERROR: Plugin 'NetworkStatus' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-08-23 14:36:18.285 Tell The DJ[14955:c07] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "NetworkStatus1096677260",
  "NetworkStatus",
  "getConnectionInfo",
  [

  ]
]
```

I installed Phonegap 3.0 with the Command Line Interface and paste my www files into the project folders. The app works fine but when i come to native functions like device ID, camera, network connections it fails and gets me this error. But I think my config.xml is right?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.helloCordova" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="http://dev.tellthedj.de" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.0.0" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="autohide-splashscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="load-url-timeout" value="60000" />
    <preference name="show-splashscreen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="allow-inline-media-playback" value="false" />
    <preference name="launch-mode" value="standard" />
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <plugins>
        <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
    </plugins>
</widget>
```

Comment: Have you ever managed to resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same and reinstall as suggested below didn't help. I'm wondering what needs to be done here to get it working.

Comment: I still don´t have figured this out. But I´m using iOS7, and still waiting for the official release of phongap for iOS7. Maybe it works with the new phonegap release. What kind of iOS do you use?

Comment: @ZoltanMagyar look for my answer! ;)

Comment: 6.1.3 here. Meanwhile I have resolved the issue by starting the project from scratch and installing all the cordova plugins with 'phonegap local plugin add' before building for iOS.

Comment: Does anyone have a different solution? I reinstall the plugin and also I installed phonegap and nodejs again. I also removed the plugins and install them again. I don't want to do a freshproject again.

Comment: try to copy your html, img, js and css files to desktop and then install phonegap to a complete new direction. then paste the files back

Comment: This may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301518/phonegap-3-doesnt-copy-plugins-to-platforms-folder/18311741#18311741

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I was using PhoneGap 3.0/3.1 and was removing the local build folder before rebuilding (since I had to copy icons and stuff in a secondary build script). This broke my plugins and produced this same error message.

In the end I found I had to remove `./plugins/ios.json` when removing `./platforms/ios` to make sure the plugins were rebuilt.

Comment: This is the best answer I think.

Comment: Thanks. And regenerating the correct one with `$ cordova ios prepare/build`

Comment: how to remove ./plugins/ios.json

Comment: @nuteron: You're asking how to delete a file? rm plugins/ios.json

Comment: Deleting the platforms/ios folder is not a solution if you made manual customizations to the xcode project. See my answer below for an alternative.

Comment: WOW! Magic :D love it

Comment: For me, this answer worked, even though my problems were with the File plugin instead of the plugins m1crdy was using.

Answer (score 52):

**Deleting the platforms/ios folder is not a solution for me** as all manual customizations to the xcode project will be lost.

But there is a simple way around:

> In XCode, goto Build Phases -> open the Compiled Sources dropdown.
>   Click + and add the missing plugin .m file that should be in your
>   Plugins directory (but is missing from the compiled sources).

This solution came from another stack overflow answer, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21148428/80254

**Another alternative:**

In xcode make sure the source files of the plugin has the 'target membership' settings set: In File-Explorer go to Plugins > CDVDevice.m and check if there is a tick next to your app name at "target membership" on the right side of xcode window. This actually does the same as the other solution but is a bit more convenient.

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576744/80254

Comment: Your first solution worked! Mind you, I then had a problem with the Notifications plugin, which was resolved according to this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012394/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-while-building-cordova-3-4-application

Comment: Worked for me as well, thanks..
quite bad that cordova looses out randomly plugins file..i lost half a day on this glitch

Comment: "Target membership" usually works for me.. BUT.. how can you do this for cordova run ios (not via XCode)? I ask because I use (very useful!) ionic live-reload for rapid development, and I still haven't figured out if/how I can do live-reload using XCode.

Answer (score 17):

I encountered the same issue. I have followed the solution given by Jeffrey Van Alstine. This is my script for building and testing an iOS app developed using Phonegap 3.0/3.1.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Killing xcode..."
kill $(ps aux | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}')
rm -r platforms/ios
rm plugins/ios.json
phonegap build ios
open platforms/ios/*.xcodeproj
```

Save it as a bash file, for example, `ios.sh` into your working directory (directory that contains `www` folder) and run `./ios.sh`

Comment: This comes in very handy when rebuilding a lot.

Comment: Deleting the platforms/ios folder is not a solution if you made manual customizations to the xcode project. See my answer below for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known issue for 3.* versions

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4971

you can solve this by upgrading Phonegap to release 3.4.

Comment: Upgraded from 3.3 to 3.4.1 and this did not fix my issue. Also removed and re-added all plugins to get latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling the plugin:

phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git

Comment: reinstalling the plugin doesn't work and neither does cleaning the build before rebuilding. @bjunix solution worked

Comment: @Zanderi probably because my suggestion is over a year old. I think Phonegap has improved a bit since then and released a few new versions to correct these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I use Cordova 3.7 and I solved the problem with Kobkrit Viriyayudhakorn 's solution, BUT of course you need to use

```
cordova build ios
```

instead of

```
phonegap build ios
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use the correct config.xml
for me, it is Xcode project target folder config.xml, and not platform www folder

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that worked for me. I was using with the Compass plugin and after adding the plugin I have noticed that the config.xml (plugin docs) says it should have

```
    <feature name="Compass">
    <param name="ios-package" value="**CDVLocation**" />
</feature>
```

while the ios.json in plugin has added

```
        "config.xml": {
        "/*": {
            "<feature name=\"Compass\"><param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"**CDVCompass**\" /></feature>": 1,
            "<feature name=\"Device\"><param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"CDVDevice\" /></feature>": 1
        }
```

One of then refers to CDVCompass while the other CDVLocation ... changing the xml to CDVCompass did the trick and now the app is working.

Answer (score 0):

I am so tired of removing and re-adding platforms for plugin issues! It seems like it is still a problem even now (2014/10) where if you add plugins to an app after adding platforms the plugin sometime does not get propagated down to the corresponding platform folders/etc. Note this seems to mainly affect iOS - not Android.

I think my solution is just an updated method of doing same thing bjunix posted earlier - but in XCode 6 to fix this sort of thing without removing/re-adding my platform I:

- Expand my App/Plugins folder in the left project navigator panel
- Click on each plugin file in the list that is currently in red text (one at time)
- Jump to the right side (Utilities) panel and click the folder icon in the Identity and Type section to re-link it to the actual file (see screenshot below).

After doing the above my project finally builds.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, it seems the xcode npm package responsible for making changes to the pbxproj file sometimes leaves references to plugin files that have been removed. I have not tracked down under what exact circumstances this occurs, but it appears to happen from frequent plugin remove/add operations (to update a plugin for example).

I suspect that when a plugin is removed and the xcode npm package fails at its job, it is only able to remove the plugin file references from the PBXBuildFile section but no other sections, leaving the pbxproj in a broken state.

When the xcode npm package attempts to add the plugin file references again, it first checks if the references are already in pbxproj. It looks in the PBXFileReference section, and since it finds references to the plugin in there, aborts further processing, getting us nowhere.

My solution, albeit a hack when it comes down to it, is to force the xcode npm package to check the PBXBuildFile section instead. That section will be missing the references and in turn the plugin will be re-installed correctly.

Change `pbxFileReferenceSection` to `pbxBuildFileSection` on this line: https://github.com/alunny/node-xcode/blob/master/lib/pbxProject.js#L620

Re-install your plugins, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I my case After install Paypal Plugin I am facing issue.

I resolved its by add "PayPalMobileCordovaPlugin.m"  in the Compile Source.

So you just need to add .m file in Compile source add it works for me.

Check Screenshot.[image: Screenshot After Add .m File]

Hope its work for you

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have a plugin that is referenced but not installed. If you have tried the above solutions and can't find the referenced plugin's .m file it might be that the plugin isn't really installed.

I would check your plugins directory to be sure that there are files in it.  If not, reinstall the plugin.  I ran into this when I had a typo in the git repo when restoring plugins from the config.xml.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue by changing the "plugin" entry to a "feature" entry in the config.xml. (using PhoneGap 3.1/iOS). This is what the fix looked like:

```
<feature name="DGGeofencing">
    <param name="ios-package" value="DGGeofencing"/>
</feature>
```

Answer (score -4):

I solved this issue with complete reinstall of Node.js and Phonegap through the CLI Tool

Comment: Can't understand why this would be marked as the answer. It's clearly a 'reinstall Windows' type of solution while the actual solution is way easier.