# Cordova InAppBrowser does not display anything in iOS (Xcode 6)

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-3, inappbrowser, xcode6-beta7

I've been looking all over, but can not understand what's wrong with my program. I had no problems with Xcode 5. Now I'm running Cordova 3.5 with InAppBrowser 0.5.1 through Xcode 6 beta 7, and can't get InAppBrowser to do anything on iOS7.

I'm open to a bug in my JavaScript, but so far the plugin's values are set in the config.xml (added automatically by Cordova):

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

values are set properly in ios/www/cordova_plugins.js:

```
{
  "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js",
   "id": "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.inappbrowser",
   "clobbers": [
       "window.open"
   ]
}
```

and

```
module.exports.metadata = {
  "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser": "0.5.1"
}
```

the javascript file is loaded when app starts. I added logs to *module.exports* inside InAppBrowser.js, and if I call "window.open" InAppBrowser responds (message logged to console), but nothing is happening on screen!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why things didn't work, but I updated Cordova 3.5 to 3.6, then the four plugins I used to:

- Device 0.2.11
- Notification 0.2.9
- InAppBrowser 0.5.1 <-- didn't update (same version :-O )
- Splashscreen 0.3.2

Ran Prepare, then Build.

I also got two more problems after that, Device Ready never fired, and I had to add my plugins to the Build Phases according to @bjunix in this SO article:

[Phonegap 3.0 IOS plugins not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403225/phonegap-3-0-ios-plugins-not-found/23934073#comment40648990_23934073)

then fix Notification according to @Amar in this article: [Undefined symbols for architecture i386 while building Cordova 3.4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012394/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-while-building-cordova-3-4-application)