# cordova 3.3. facebook integration for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

Error:

```
2014 - 04 - 08 17: 38: 33.210 javacourseblog[10129: 907] ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect'
not found,
or is not a CDVPlugin.Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014 - 04 - 08 17: 38: 33.211 javacourseblog[10129: 907] - [CDVCommandQueue executePending][Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = ["org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect1333284177", "org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect", "login", ["email"]]
```

this my error;

i tried to Facebook login& logout using cordova

i followed this bellow blog page.

http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/01/facebook-login-logout-using-cordova-330.html

android facebook login is working fine. but iOS build it shows above error.i followed

[Phonegap 3.0 IOS plugins not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403225/phonegap-3-0-ios-plugins-not-found/19501579#19501579)

also its also not helping for me.. please any one can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1:
 create cordova project via telnet:

```
cordova create facebook in.com.fb Facebook
```

step 2:
   add facebook cordova plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git
```

step 3:
     remove and add fb id & app name .open the plugin.xml file from

```
  find and remove below 2 line
```

```
 after to add this 2 line
```

step 4
   add your platform for android or ios
     cordova platform add ios
step 5 
    1.Now Make reference of cordova.js ,cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js and facebook-js-sdk.js in your www folder
     2.remove your old code form index.html.add follwoing code find replace your fb app id in index.html
'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
            <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
            <title>Hello World</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="app">
                <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
                <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                    <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                    <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="facebook_js_sdk.js"></script>


            <div id="data">Hello Facebooktesters, loading ...</div>

        <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
        <button onclick="me()">Me</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                try {
                    alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
                    FB.init({
                        appId : "Your fb Id",
                        nativeInterface : CDV.FB,
                        useCachedDialogs : false
                    });
                    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "FB init executed";
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            }, false);

            function me() {
                FB.api('/me/friends', {
                    fields : 'id, name, picture'
                }, function(response) {
                    if (response.error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
                    } else {
                        var data = document.getElementById('data');
                        fdata = response.data;
                        console.log("fdata: " + fdata);
                        response.data.forEach(function(item) {
                            var d = document.createElement('div');
                            d.innerHTML = "<img src="+item.picture+"/>" + item.name;
                            data.appendChild(d);
                        });
                    }
                    var friends = response.data;
                    console.log(friends.length);
                    for ( var k = 0; k < friends.length && k < 200; k++) {
                        var friend = friends[k];
                        var index = 1;

                        friendIDs[k] = friend.id;
                        //friendsInfo[k] = friend;
                    }
                    console.log("friendId's: " + friendIDs);
                });
            }

            function login() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        alert('logged in');
                    } else {
                        alert('not logged in');
                    }
                }, {
                    scope : "email"
                });
            }
        </script>
         <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
                app.initialize();
            </script> -->
        </body>
    </html>'
```

step 6:
    open your project in xcode and open ios plist file and add your fb appid and fb app_name
step 7
     go to your codova config.xml.find bellow this line exits or not..if not exits(ios) add to step..

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
        <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
    </feature>
```

step 8

cordova build

step 9
    again check plist file
step 10
    run your ios simulator

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install your facebook phonegap plugin in proper way. Don't use plugman.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --variable APP_NAME=“YourAppName”
```

Comment: Ya..i installed proper way...thanks for replay..i found solution...its configuration issue.i sorted out.now its working for me in ios.