# phonegap oauthio plugin wont load

Tags: ios, cordova

Im testing the phone gap oauthio plugin but cannot get it to work

followed the docs.

added the plugin with the command line
and also  installed inappbrowser

also added this to my config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.oauthio" />
```

the inappbrowser its loaded and working.
but the OAUTH is not.
i added some alert() here and there
but when i add an alert to display the content o OAUTH it won't happen

```
alert('device ready'); //to see if the device is ready, no problems here
alert(window.open); //to see if inbrowserapp is loaded, no problems here
alert(OAuth);// no message. looks like is not defined,also tried alert(OAuth.initialize) same luck
OAuth.initialize("VeQmyEu0QtzIOO9WjM1IlAU0ty4");
alert('postinit');
```

inside the plugin the definition says "OAuth" so the name is ok and my installed plugins are

```
oauthio-test % phonegap plugin list
[phonegap] com.phonegap.plugins.oauthio
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

i also delete the contents of "platform/ios" to prevent file caching

my access are these

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<access origin="*graph.facebook.com*" />
<access origin="*api.twitter.com*" />
<access origin="*github.com*" />
```

no luck so far.
it felts like when I debuged in IE6

EDIT:
Added the full code that shows that im inside an event 'ondeviceready'

```
 $(document).on('deviceready', function() {
    alert('device ready');//shows ok
    alert(window.open); //shows ok
    alert(OAuth.OAuth.initialize);//it dies here
            OAuth.initialize("VeQmyEu0QtzIOO9WjM1IlAU0ty4");
    alert('postinit');//this alert won't displayed
            $('#fb-connect').on('click', function() {
                $('#result').html("");
                OAuth.popup("facebook", function(e,r) {
                    if (e)
                        $('#result').html('error: ' + e.message);
                    else
                        // the access_token is available via r.access_token
                        // but the http functions automagically wrap the jquery calls
                        r.get('/me').done(function(data) {
                            $('#result').html("facebook: Hello, " + data.name + " !");
                        });
                });
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `<access origin="*" />` the others aren't needed if you have that, and I'm not 100% they are stackable (meaning the last one may be the only one getting used)

Comment: I just added it in my last try and also tried what you said. still the same result. is like is not being loaded and i don't know hoy to debug this :(

Comment: are you making sure to only call the plugin after the `deviceready` event has fired? If not, I can give an example

Comment: yep. i added more code. the sad thing is that i used the example on the plugin site and even that doesn't work

Comment: This line is not correct `alert(OAuth.OAuth.initialize);//it dies here` I think you mean `alert(OAuth);`. Is that just a typo above or in actual source?

Comment: it died without it anyways. but you were right the line was indeed bad. but i made it. the problem was with plugins/ios.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. so looks like it's a phone gap bug.

If you add a plugin later you need to clean up your platform and plugins/*.json files

I followed this post and the plugins were builded and installed correctly

[Phonegap 3.0 IOS plugins not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403225/phonegap-3-0-ios-plugins-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

in terminal you need to past this url and enter

"**phonegap plugin add https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap** ".

and you can use android or iOS simulator to run the application.

Comment: thanks but it was answered by me in the next post.  gladly we finished this project an sweared to any old deity to never get near of any that go near PhoneGap