# CDVPlugin class CBLite (pluginName: CBLite) does not exist

Tags: cordova, couchbase, cordova-3, cordova-plugins, pouchdb

After reading this article [PouchDB vs. Couchbase Lite - a performance review](http://www.mircozeiss.com/pouchdb-vs-couchbase-lite-a-performance-review/), I was excited to try running the code https://github.com/zeMirco/pouchdb-vs-couchbase

The app did not run at first. I deleted the platforms and rebuilt:

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova build ios
```

Then I ran the app using iPad retina 64-bit emulator. I noticed the console outputted the following.

```
2014-05-30 14:38:08.518 HelloCordova[50407:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-05-30 14:38:08.526 HelloCordova[50407:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-05-30 14:38:08.532 HelloCordova[50407:60b] 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines"
You could find it at the following address https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/ .

2014-05-30 14:38:08.594 HelloCordova[50407:60b] CDVPlugin class CBLite (pluginName: cblite) does not exist.
2014-05-30 14:38:08.594 HelloCordova[50407:60b] [CDVTimer][cblite] 0.567973ms
2014-05-30 14:38:08.595 HelloCordova[50407:60b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 1.537025ms
2014-05-30 14:38:09.162 HelloCordova[50407:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-05-30 14:38:09.295 HelloCordova[50407:60b] Finished load of: file:///Users/jshultz/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/FDA667F2-50BD-48D0-836C-D42F358F6A3F/HelloCordova.app/www/index.html
2014-05-30 14:38:09.408 HelloCordova[50407:60b] CDVPlugin class CBLite (pluginName: CBLite) does not exist.
2014-05-30 14:38:09.409 HelloCordova[50407:60b] ERROR: Plugin 'CBLite' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-05-30 14:38:09.409 HelloCordova[50407:60b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "CBLite1387911234",
  "CBLite",
  "getURL",
  [

  ]
]
```

I think there is an error loading the Couchbase lite plugin which I tried reinstalling and Cordova reports that it is already installed.

```
$ cordova plugin add com.couchbase.lite.phonegap
Fetching plugin "com.couchbase.lite.phonegap" via plugin registry
Plugin "com.couchbase.lite.phonegap" already installed on ios.
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding the line:

```
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local" />
```

to the config.xml file makes this warning go away.  Apparently the default is now "cloud".

See:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html#iOS%20Configuration

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to delete the ios.json in the folder plugins? Because propably cordova thinks that the plugin is already installed. After that you have to build your app again.

Or you could also try to delete the whole platform-folder...

Comment: I am trying this now. After deleting ios.json I ran `cordova build ios`, then ran the xcode project. The message says couchbase lite is not installed. Only button that triggers a response is the first clear db. Now I see no errors in the XCode console. I think this removed the plugin but maybe I need to try reinstalling it?

Comment: I looked at the cordova plugins. It says I have Couchbase Lite installed `$ cordova plugin
com.couchbase.lite.phonegap 1.0.0 "Couchbase Lite"
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.2.10-dev "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.8 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.4.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.9-dev "Network Information"`

Comment: have you tried to delete the whole platform-folder?
do you wait for the cordovaready-event?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a duplicate of [Phonegap 3.0 IOS plugins not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403225/phonegap-3-0-ios-plugins-not-found)

I've found the most efficient solution to be that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23934073/2020919 
i.e.

> In XCode, goto Build Phases -> open the Compiled Sources dropdown. Click + and add the missing plugin .m file that should be in your Plugins directory (but is missing from the compiled sources).