# PushPlugin "does not exist" Cordova 3.5

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I am following [this](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) tutorial to implement Push Notifications into my PhoneGap application. However I keep getting the following error in XCode:

```
2014-06-03 22:50:38.425 Clubbed In[336:60b] CDVPlugin class PushPlugin (pluginName: PushPlugin) does not exist.
2014-06-03 22:50:38.425 Clubbed In[336:60b] ERROR: Plugin 'PushPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-06-03 22:50:38.427 Clubbed In[336:60b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
"PushPlugin1224815266",
"PushPlugin",
"register",
[
 {
  "alert" : "true",
  "ecb" : "onNotificationAPN",
  "sound" : "true",
  "badge" : "true"
 }
]
```

I have put the 4 delegate/plugin files into my project's plugin folder successfully. In addition, I have added the PushNotification.js and referenced it correctly. I also have the following feature tags in my config.xml:

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error? I am pretty sure that I correctly manually installed this PushPlugin.

Do the 4 files go into the Classes folder of CordovaLib?
In the plugins folder should I include a folder called com.plugin.PushPlugin, then put the 4 files within that?

Any help would truly be appreciated. I have been stuck on this problem for a long time...

Thanks!

Comment: this worked for me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403225/phonegap-3-0-ios-plugins-not-found

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have not build the IOS platform. remember to execute the build command every time you add a plugin.

the following sequence should let you have a proper phonegap/cordova project.

```
1. create the project
2. add the platform
3. add the plugins
4. build the platform
```

Comment: I am using non CLI version and XCode to build and run the app. Shouldn't that be the same?

Comment: non CLI's wont yield the same results... did tasted it! we were working with PG on WP8 where the NON-CLI setup didn't provide us with  FILE/ File Transfer plugin support. we had to do it through the CLI method and it worked.

Comment: To do it through the CLI method, do I need to create a new CLI project? Is there anyway I can use the same project?

Comment: yes. you have to create a new project environment. but you just have to replace your new project's default www folder with your existing project's www folder. (remember not to copy cordova or phonegap plugins from the www folder). this should give you access to what ever plugin you might have added through CLI...

Comment: If I create a new project environment, then how do I transfer my XCode project to this new environment?

Comment: I don't want an entire new XCode project, where I have to re-set up the entire project